# Python - Decay curve_fit breaks down in plot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to plot values from a recorded data set from an experiment.

When fitting the data with an exponential decay, it's very successful in the form of a normal plot.

[image]

But having the plot in a semi-log form gives me this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pylab as plb
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Run-4 Data
DecayTime4 = []
DecayCount4 = []

with open('Half_Life_Run4_Decay_AD.csv', 'r') as h:
    reader = csv.reader(h, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        DecayTime4.append(row[0])
        DecayCount4.append(row[1])

DecayTime4 = np.array(DecayTime4) 
DecayCount4 = np.array(DecayCount4)


def model_func(x, a, k, b):
    return a * np.exp(-k*x) + b


# Run 4 Data Fitting plot
x4 = np.float32(DecayTime4) 
y4 = np.float32(DecayCount4) 

p0_R4 = (1.,1.e-5,1.) 
optR4, pcovR4 = curve_fit(model_func, x4, y4, p0_R4)
aR4, kR4, bR4 = optR4
aR4p, kR4p, bR4p = pcovR4
y4M = model_func(x4, aR4, kR4, bR4)

fig4 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
ax4 = fig4.add_subplot(111)
# Plot of data
ax4.plot(DecayTime4, DecayCount4, ".", color='lightcoral')
# Plot of best fit
ax4.plot(x4, y4M, color='k', label='Fitting Function: $f(t) = %0.2f e^{%0.3f\ t} %+0.2f$' % (aR4,kR4,bR4))

ax4.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax4.set_ylabel('Count')
ax4.set_title('Run 4 of Cesium-137 Decay')
ax4.set_yscale('log')
ax4.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), prop={'size':15}, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
```

[image]

The purpose of the semi-log is to show the accuracy of the exponential fit with the data.

It should real be a straight line like this image

[image]

The data set is large with a shape of `(1401,)`.

Could it be that the curve_fit must not work well with large data sets?

Can this be correct?

Comment: It looks like you data in the csv file may not be written with sufficient accuracy (~1 decimal place). This may explain the spread at the bottom on the semilog plot. If you increase the number of decimal places and cut the y axis limits at 0.001 you may get closer to the required form.

Comment: @EdSmith I see. Would `np.around()` be efficient in adding decimal places?

Comment: I meant the data in `Half_Life_Run4_Decay_AD.csv` may not be sufficiently accurate... If this is the case then you need to regenerate this (from simulation or experiment with longer runs/more sample counts), nothing you can do in post processing will help, although you can cut the y axis at about `y=5` to at least show a linear graph. If you think the csv is at sufficient accuracy then it may be something else in you code. It would be useful to upload you csv data so people can help you further in that case.

Comment: *"It should real be a straight line..."*  It won't be a straight line because your model (i.e. the function you are fitting to the data) includes a constant offset term `b`.

Comment: ... so, if you really expect the semi-log plot to be a straight line, it means you expect the parameter `b` to be 0.  If that is the case, you should remove that parameter from your model.

Comment: The problem is that the data set has no decimal places like Ed Smith. So I would have to manually input decimal places to all these values in the CSV file. Or apply some for loop.

Comment: In fact, since you are modeling the decay of Cesium-147, that parameter `b` doesn't make physical sense.  `b` is the long-term quantity remaining, but there shouldn't be a long-term quantity--decay continues indefinitely (and a *negative* value makes even less sense to me!).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Funny thing is, this is an isolated sample. I did two runs that were not isolated from the detector and got better results for some reason. But that is most likely due to the CVS file not being exported with it's decimal values.

Comment: Missing decimal places or not, if `b` is not zero, the semi-log graph is not a straight line.  In some cases, the part that you plot might *look like* a straight line, but if `b` is positive, the semi-log graph will eventually level off and approach a constant, and if `b` is negative, there will be a vertical asymptote at the value of `x` where `a * exp(-k*x) == b` (which is apparently what is happening in your plot).